# Distance between two surfaces when rotateY

Tags: javascript, html, css, famo.us

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/8gg7gkqv/

I want the red surface sits flat on top of the gray surface. But you can see the distance (marked ??) between two surfaces when I rotate `modifier1`. How to get rid of this "gap"?

[image]

**JS:**

```
Famous.loaded(function () {
    var Engine = Famous.Core.Engine;
    var Surface = Famous.Core.Surface;
    var Modifier = Famous.Core.Modifier;
    var Transform = Famous.Core.Transform;
    var StateModifier = Famous.Modifiers.StateModifier;
    var Easing = Famous.Transitions.Easing;

    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
    mainContext.setPerspective(1000);

    var modifier1 = new StateModifier({
      size: [200, 200],
      align: [0.5, 0.5],
      origin: [0.5, 0.5]
    });

    var surface1 = new Surface({
      properties: {
        background: 'gray'
      }
    });

    var modifier2 = new StateModifier({
      size: [50, 100],
      align: [0.5, 0.5],
      origin: [0.5, 0.5]
    });

    var surface2 = new Surface({
      properties: {
        background: 'red'
      }
    });

    var graphNode = mainContext.add(modifier1);
    graphNode.add(surface1);
    graphNode.add(modifier2).add(surface2);

    modifier1.setTransform(
      Transform.rotate(0, Math.PI/2.2, 0),
      { duration: 2000, curve: Easing.outElastic }
    );

    modifier2.setTransform(
      Transform.scale(1, 2, 1),
      { duration: 2000, curve: Easing.outElastic }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Never seen this library but I think I fixed the problem correctly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/8gg7gkqv/1/), just the explanation may be lacking:

```
var graphNode = mainContext.add(modifier1);
graphNode.add(surface1);
1graphNode.add(modifier2).add(surface2);
```

Here you add one modifier on top of the other, so the origins stack. `modifier1` is 0.5, 0.5 from the `mainContext`. But `modifier2` has the same origin but it's applied relative to `modifier1` which is where the extra distance comes from.

The solution is to set the origin of `modifier2` to `0,0`, or add it to `mainContext`. I think the former is what you want.

**EDIT:** fixed fiddle link

Comment: It works but now the red bar is not center any more. I can fix it with some Transform.translate with hardcoded number but would love to know how to avoid doing that and let the align/origin to take care automatically.

Comment: Actually creating another modifier just for the centering seems work: http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/8gg7gkqv/4/